# Combined to date and time fields into one when both datetime stamps

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I am trying to combine the date and time part of a table so that I can set appointments correctly I was wondering if someone could help me my syntax is not being compiled

```
 public List<Appointment> getAppointments (DateTime AppointmentDate)
 {
    List<Appointment> query = _sourceEntities.Appointments.Where(a => a.ApptDate == AppointmentDate && a.ClientID==6).ToList();
    return _sourceEntities.Appointments.Select(r =>

    {
            var newAppointment = new Appointment();
            DateTime date = new DateTime(r.ApptDate.Year, r.ApptDate.Month, r.ApptDate.Day, r.ApptTime.Hour, r.ApptTime.Minute, r.ApptTime.Second);
            newAppointment.ApptDate = date;
            return newAppointment();


    });

}
```

The error is hapening here  return newAppointment(); I am not sure why its saying method name expected I want to have all the fields of the old list but also this new combined date time field.

Here is the example of the data to best explain

https://i.stack.imgur.com/EAtUT.png

**Edit 2**

The _sourceEntites is decalred heree at the top of the class

```
public class SourceContext 
{
     public  SMBASchedulerEntities _sourceEntities = new SMBASchedulerEntities();
     public static List<Appointment> getAppointments(DateTime apptDate)
     List<Appointment> query = _sourceEntities.Appointments.Where(a => a.ApptDate == AppointmentDate && a.ClientID==6).ToList();
     return _sourceEntities.Appointments.Select(r =>

    {
            var newAppointment = new Appointment();
            DateTime date = new DateTime(r.ApptDate.Year, r.ApptDate.Month, r.ApptDate.Day, r.ApptTime.Hour, r.ApptTime.Minute, r.ApptTime.Second);
            newAppointment.ApptDate = date;
            return newAppointment();


    });
}
```

Comment: `return newAppointment();` should be `return newAppointment`;

Comment: As @MethodMan points out, newAppointment is a variable not a function. Therefore, you don't need the '()''s.

Comment: Also, you aren't using the `query` anywhere...

Answer (score 0):

newAppointment is an object variable, by using ('s the compiler treats newAppointment  as a method, that is what the error message states. Removing the ('s should solve the problem.

An alternative way to return the result would be

```
public List<Appointment> getAppointments (DateTime AppointmentDate)
 {
    List<Appointment> query = _sourceEntities.Appointments.Where(a => a.ApptDate == AppointmentDate && a.ClientID==6).ToList();
    return _sourceEntities.Appointments.Select(r => new Appointment

    {
            newAppointment.ApptDate = ew DateTime(r.ApptDate.Year, r.ApptDate.Month, r.ApptDate.Day, r.ApptTime.Hour, r.ApptTime.Minute, r.ApptTime.Second);
            //map other variables here
    });

}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your code is in the line: `return newAppointment();`. You are treating the object `newAppointment` like a method when you add the parenthesis after it. Instead, you can just do:

```
return newAppointment;
```

A slightly simpler approach would be to create a new `Appointment` in your `Select` statement. This will return an `IEnumerable` of `Appointment` objects, which we can the call `ToList()` on before returning. I also included a `.Where()` clause to match what you had in your `query`. You can remove that line if it's not needed.

```
public static List<Appointment> getAppointments(DateTime apptDate)
{
    return _sourceEntities.Appointments
        .Where(a => a.ApptDate == apptDate && a.ClientID == 6) // Remove if not needed
        .Select(r =>
            new Appointment
            {
                ApptDate = new DateTime(r.ApptDate.Year, r.ApptDate.Month, r.ApptDate.Day,
                    r.ApptTime.Hour, r.ApptTime.Minute, r.ApptTime.Second)
            })
        .ToList();
}
```

One other thing to note is that you are doing an equality comparison on the two date objects, so you will only be getting appointments for the exact date **and time** of the argument passed in. In case you want to get all the appointments for **the day**, you can just use the `Date` portion of the `DateTime` objects for comparison:

```
// Compare the Date portion of the argument to get all appointments for that day
.Where(a => a.ApptDate.Date == appointment.Date && a.ClientID == 6)
```

Comment: when i try that i get the following Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State
Error CS0120 An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'SourceContext._sourceEntities' SMBAScheduler C:\Projects\Backup of Paitent Source Code\WindowsFormsApplication1\SourceContext.cs 14 Active

Comment: Strange. Where is `_sourceEntities` defined? Is it instantiated? I was just using your existing code for that...

Comment: I found the issue it was cause it was static however when i tried it it gave me back the following error Additional information: The entity or complex type 'SMBASchedulerModel.Appointment' cannot be constructed in a LINQ to Entities query.